# Redmine 3.3.0 sometimes send emails with changes and sometimes not

Tags: redmine

We have an issue that has three changes in the history.
These 3 changes should be sent by email to:

user1@company1.com, user2@company2.com, user3@company3.com

Only changes 1 and 3 reached all the recipients. Change 2 didn't reach user2@company2.com

If a search in the sent folder in my Outlook I can't find the email with the second change to user2@company2.com, so I think Redmine didn't send it for any reason.

Anyone know what might be happening?

Update:
Here we can see the log and I understand that the mail is render and sent. But only user1 get it, user2 and user3 don´t. I asked for the smtp server log and there is not any clue about the message for user2 and user3

```
     Sent email "issue name" (0ms)
     bcc: user1@company.es
     Rendered mailer/_issue.text.erb (0.0ms)
     Rendered mailer/issue_edit.text.erb within layouts/mailer (0.0ms)
     Rendered mailer/_issue.html.erb (15.6ms)
     Rendered mailer/issue_edit.html.erb within layouts/mailer (31.2ms)

     Sent email "issue name" (0ms)
     bcc: user2@company.com, user3@company.com
     Redirected to http://helpdesk.company.es/redmine/issues/58385? 
     next_issue_id=58366&prev_issue_id=58394
     Completed 302 Found in 1092ms (ActiveRecord: 218.4ms)
     Started GET "/redmine/issues/58385? 
     next_issue_id=58366&prev_issue_id=58394" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-08-22 
     10:54:40 +0200
     Processing by IssuesController#show as HTML
```

Comment: The right answer to the question "Had the email been sent?" you can find only in SMTP server logs. If all users are from the same `@company.com` and `user1` and `user3` have received the email, then probably there were some issues with `user2` mailbox at that time.

Comment: No, the 3 users are from different companies, but the user 2 receives email with the first change and the third, but not the second. For that reason I can´t imagine what is happening because there is some changes yes and some not

Comment: Then you should begin with SMTP server logs.

Comment: I have seen that in redmine log that after the mailer of the previous email that is sent:                                    
Rendered mailer/_issue.text.erb (0.0ms)
Rendered mailer/issue_edit.text.erb within layouts/mailer (15.6ms)
Rendered mailer/_issue.html.erb (0.0ms)
Rendered mailer/issue_edit.html.erb within layouts/mailer (0.0ms)
I have:
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 50981ms (ActiveRecord: 50746.9ms)

Comment: If you are experiencing error 500, it might be related to email, try running your Redmine in debug mode, it might reveal more info in log.

Comment: Are you using any Redmine plugin?

Comment: No, I am not. As I say in the update in redmine log seems that teh email was created and sent but in the smtp server log there is not any track of the email for user2 and user3